# Numpy linspace unexpected output

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am running the code below to build a one-dimensional array for each z and t. At the present moment, I am trying to make their sizes equivalent so that they each have a length of 501.

```
import numpy as np

#constants & parameters
omega = 1.
eps = 1.
c = 3.*(10.**8.)
hbar = 1.
eta = 0.01
nn = 10.**7. 
n = eta*nn 

lambdaOH = c/(1612.*10.**(6.)) 
gamma = 1.282*(10.**(-11.))
Tsp = 1./gamma
TR = 604800. 
L = (Tsp/TR)*(np.pi)/((3.*(lambdaOH**2.))*n)

#time
Ngridt = 500.
tmax = 1. 
dt = tmax/Ngridt
intervalt = tmax/dt + 1 
t = np.linspace(0.01,tmax,intervalt)

#z space
Ngridz = 500.
zmax = L
dz = zmax/Ngridz 
intervalz = zmax/dz + 1
z = np.linspace(0.01,zmax,intervalz)
```

When running the code, both intervalt and intervalz equal 501.0, but when checking the length of both z and t, len(z) = 500 while len(t) = 501. I have played around with the code above to yield len(z) = 501 by modifying certain parts. For example, if I insert the code

```
zmax = int(zmax)
```

then len(z) = 501. But I am wondering why the initial code, exactly as written, does not yield an array z with length 501?

(I am using Python 2.7.)

Comment: I get intervalz = 500.99999999999994, which is not equal to 501 and explains the output. Maybe use: intervalz = np.ceil(zmax/dz + 1)

Comment: If you want the length to be equal, why do you then calculate the length two times ? You can just calculate one "interval" and the use it for both? Why bother calculating intervalz and intervalt ?

Comment: I've found in these types of things it's always useful to add a `1E-10` to your limits to avoid the floating point issues remarked upon by Nikolas.

Comment: @NikolasRieble It is only this particular case I wanted them to be equal. I will be changing the lengths in the future.

Comment: @zephyr Thank you for both of your input. Either method has fixed the problem. It seems dependent on the application, but is adding 1E-10 in general a better idea than np.ceil for any particular reason?

Comment: @Mathews24 `np.ceil` would work just fine in this case, and indeed most cases. I think which one you go with is a matter of preference. I use the `1E-10` trick on things like `np.arange(1,10+1E-10,0.01)` where I want to include 10 in my array.

Comment: The whole to using `linspace` is to avoid rounding issues like this when using `arange` with intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem of rounding. If you try to subtract 501 from intervalz you will find a very small negative number, -5.68e-14; linspace just takes the integer part of it, that is 500, and provides a 500-long list.

Notice two other problems with your code:

1. `dt` does not provide the correct spacing because you don't remove the initial `t` (same for `dz`)
2. `Ngridt` and `Ngridz` are conceptually integers, while you initialize them as floats. Just remove the dot at the end.

I think that your code could be simplified by writing (notice that `Ngridt` and `Ngridz` are initialized to 501)

```
#time
Ngridt = 501
tmax = 1. 
t, dt = np.linspace(0.01,tmax,Ngridt,retstep=True)

#z space
Ngridz = 501
zmax = L
z, dz = np.linspace(0.01,zmax,Ngridz,retstep=True)
```

Comment: I edited the answer because I forgot dz in the last line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to float arithmetic inaccuracy. It so happens that the formula for `intervalz` yields `500.99999999999994`. This is just floating accuracy issue you can find all over SO. The `np.linspace` command then takes this number as 500 and not as 501.

Since `linspace` expects an `int` it is better to make sure you give it one.

BTW: mathematically speaking I don't see why you don't set

```
intervalz = Ngridz + 1
```

since `intervalz = zmax/dz + 1 = zmax/(zmax/Ngridz) + 1 = Ngridz + 1`